# How to map HTML to in NSAttributedString in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsattributedstring, foundation

Since the NSAttributedString initWithHTML addtion is only availiable on Mac OS but not iOS.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The only way to show formatted strings of text is to use a UIWebView. Otherwise you're going to have to render layers on top of your text.

Comment: @Thomas actually since iOS 3.2 there is also Core Text, which is the technology this question is about. You can render rich text without a UIWebView, and even using custom fonts embedded in the application.

Answer (score 1):

You should check Oliver Drobnik's [NSAttributedString Additions for HTML](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) project on GitHub. It is a response to precisely that problem. See also [his blog post](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/uiwebview-must-die/) about it.