# NSAttributedString.initWithHTML not available in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, nsattributedstring, xamarin

seems the `initWithHTML` was not implemented on `NSAttributedString`.  I have checked out PerformSelector but its just not making sense to me and I cant find an example calling that on `NSAttributedString`.  If someone has an example it would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that `initWithHTML` is not implemented in `NSAttributedString` but it's not related to MonoTouch - it's just not available in iOS, see Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

The selector is only available as in OSX by using AppKit (see Apple's AppKit [additions documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html)).

Comment: ARRRGGGGGGG.  I needed that call!  Thank you.

Comment: You're not alone, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4075223/220643 Let us know if you find other alternatives.